# Como obtener entidades y sus relaciones utilizando Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Estoy trabajando con Spring 4 e Hibernate 5. Estoy haciendo una aplicación de prueba para gestionar los eventos de un teatro ficticio, y ademas guardar información de dichos eventos. Tengo varias clases anotadas con @Entity, tales como Teatro, Usuario, Asiento, Sala, etc, y muchas de estas clases se relacionan entre si. Estas clases ya están en mi base de datos como tablas y tienen información almacenada.

Ahora necesito mostrar en mi programa la cantidad de entidades que tengo y las relaciones entre ellas. Pero no se como mapear la base de datos para obtener mis entidades y su relaciones.

Necesito un método o procedimiento que me devuelva estos valores, por ejemplo estos serian los resultados finales:

```
Object[] entidades ={Teatro, Sala, Asiento, Persona}
String[] relaciones ={Teatro-Sala, Sala-Asiento, Teatro-Asiento, Asiento-Persona}
```

Dado que uso Hibernate y mis clases están anotadas con @Entity, he buscado alguna manera de obtener la información que quiero pero no encuentro como hacerlo. Así que, de que forma puedo obtener mis entidades y las relaciones entre ellas?

Tener presente en mi caso que algunas de las entidades pueden ser eliminadas eventualmente, por tanto habría que actualizar las cantidades de entidades y relaciones entre ellas

EDITADO

Aquí agrego el código de mi DAO, para ilustrar un ejemplo de como salvo en la base de datos:

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details="+p);
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo bien, si lo que quieres es obtener la relacion de un objeto en un momento determinado o un listado con los objetos y sus relaciones o simplemente el nombre de las clases que se relacionan, ademas lo quieres hacer para toda la base de datos de una vez o solo necesitas cargar determinados objetos? si añades algo de codigo o aclaras un poco la pregunta seguro que te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Vale, necesito obtener un listado con todos los objetos y sus relaciones, para toda la base de datos de una vez.

Comment: Añade el código de tu DAO, la capa donde haces las llamadas a la base de datos

Comment: @Javi2EE Listo, revisa la pregunta y dime si necesitas mas informacion

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: esta respuesta es aplicable hasta hibernate 5.1. A partir de 5.2 hay que partir de `EntityManagerFactory#getMetamodel()`.

La lista de entidades manejadas por hibernate la obtienes con:

```
Map<String,ClassMetadata> mapEntidades = this.sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
```

donde la clave del map es el nombre completo de la entidad. El nombre simple de cada entidad lo puedes obtener iterando sobre el map con:

```
AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) entry.getValue();
String nombreEntidad = persister.getEntityType().getReturnedClass().getSimpleName();
```

La lista de relaciones que son OneToMany o ManyToMany la obtienes con:

```
Map<String,CollectionMetadata> mapRelaciones =  this.sessionFactory.getAllCollectionMetadata();
```

y puedes obtener los nombres de las entidades relacionadas iterando sobre el map con:

```
AbstractCollectionPersister cp = (AbstractCollectionPersister) entry.getValue();
String entidadPrincipal = cp.getOwnerEntityPersister().getEntityMetamodel().getEntityType().getReturnedClass().getSimpleName();
String entidadRelacionada = cp.getElementNodeName();
```

Las relaciones ManyToOne se obtienen del `ClassMetadata` del primer map. Tienes que obtener el array de tipos de la entidad y buscar los de clase `ManyToOneType`:

```
Type[] tipos = persister.getClassMetadata().getPropertyTypes();
for (Type t : tipos) {
    if (t instanceof ManyToOneType) {
        ManyToOneType mtot = (ManyToOneType) t;
        String entidadRelacionada = mtot.getReturnedClass().getSimpleName();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: El metodo getAllClassMetadata esta obsoleto en Hibernate 5, igual que getAllColectionMetada

Comment: Lo uso en hibernate 3.6 y chequeé el javadoc de hibernate 5.0 antes de contestar. Veo ahora que en 5.2 está obsoleto. La misma información está disponible usando JPA en `EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()`. Como ahora `SessionFactory` extiende de `EntityManagerFactory` deberías poder llamarlo directamente (en el javadoc no aparece).

Comment: Yo los llamo directamente utilizando el objeto de SessionFactory, pero el getMetamodel() tambien me sale obsoleto.

Comment: `SessionFactory.getMetamodel()` devuelve una instancia de `MetamodelImplementor` que es propia de hibernate pero que extiende `Metamodel` que es de JPA. Con el método `getEntities()` obtienes un `Set<EntityType<?>>` a partir del cual puedes obtener los nombres de las entidades y para cada una puedes obtener las relaciones a partir de `Set<PluralAttribute<X,?,?>> getDeclaredPluralAttributes()`.   De esta forma cuando pases a hibernate 6 solo tendrás que cambiar como obtienes el `Metamodel`.

Comment: @Ethan (no me deja poner el comentario en tu respuesta, va acá...) por lo que seguí investigando, lo correcto es usar  `... = ((EntityManagerFactory) sf).getMetamodel().getEntities()`  para evitar el warning por obsoleto.

Comment: Garcias @jorgegm cuando lo pruebe te digo que tal resulta

Answer (score 0):

Despues de hace varias pruebas, estas son las soluciones a las que arribe. Les dejo los codigos de los dos metodos que hice. Todavia me queda la espinita con los metodos obsoletos, agradeceria sugerencias acerca de esto.

Metodo para obtener las entidades:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void listarEntidades(){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Set<EntityType<?>> entidades = sf.getMetamodel().getEntities();
        List<String> listEntities = new ArrayList<>();
          for (javax.persistence.metamodel.EntityType<?> entidad: entidades) {
              listEntities.add(new String(((EntityTypeImpl) entidad).getTypeName()));         
              }

          System.out.println("Printing entities");
          for(String x:listEntities){
              System.out.println("Entity name: "+x);
          }
    }
```

Metodo para obtener los atributos:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void listarAtributos(){
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Set<EntityType<?>> entidades = sf.getMetamodel().getEntities();
        //Set<?> listEntities;
        Set<PluralAttribute<?, ?, ?>> plural;
        Set<SingularAttributeImpl<?, ?>> single;
        for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") javax.persistence.metamodel.EntityType entidad : entidades) {
            plural = entidad.getDeclaredPluralAttributes();
            single = entidad.getSingularAttributes();
            System.out.println("****************************************");
            System.out.println(entidad.getName());
            for (PluralAttribute<?, ?, ?> x : plural) {
                System.out.println(x.getName() + "__" + x.getBindableJavaType());
            }
            for (SingularAttributeImpl<?, ?> x: single){
                System.out.println(x.getName() + "__" +x.getBindableJavaType());
            }
            }
```

Resultado impreso en la consola:

```
Entity name: com.pavel.model.Band
Entity name: com.pavel.model.ConcertHall
Entity name: com.pavel.model.Ticket
Entity name: com.pavel.model.Payment
Entity name: com.pavel.model.Seat
Entity name: com.pavel.model.Concert
Entity name: com.pavel.model.Customer
Entity name: com.pavel.model.Booking
****************************************
Band
concert__class com.pavel.model.Concert
address__class java.lang.String
bandName__class java.lang.String
activeSince__class java.lang.String
bandId__int
****************************************
ConcertHall
concerts__class com.pavel.model.Concert
seats__class com.pavel.model.Seat
address__class java.lang.String
hallId__int
hallName__class java.lang.String
****************************************
Ticket
seat__class com.pavel.model.Seat
booking__class com.pavel.model.Booking
ticketId__int
concert__class com.pavel.model.Concert
price__float
****************************************
Payment
paymentId__int
amount__float
booking__class com.pavel.model.Booking
****************************************
Seat
ticket__class com.pavel.model.Ticket
seatId__int
seatNumber__int
concertHall__class com.pavel.model.ConcertHall
seatRow__int
****************************************
Concert
bands__class com.pavel.model.Band
tickets__class com.pavel.model.Ticket
concertId__int
startTime__class java.lang.String
concertDate__class java.lang.String
concertHall__class com.pavel.model.ConcertHall
****************************************
Customer
customerBirthDate__class java.lang.String
customerName__class java.lang.String
customerAddress__class java.lang.String
customerId__int
booking__class com.pavel.model.Booking
****************************************
Booking
tickets__class com.pavel.model.Ticket
payment__class com.pavel.model.Payment
customer__class com.pavel.model.Customer
totalPrice__float
bookingId__int
```

Las relaciones entre clases ya las puedo inferir porque los atributos me dicen con cual o cuales entidades se relaciona la entidad impresa. Espero que estas soluciones les sirvan.

Comment: @jorgegm Debo agregar que la propuesta de jorgegm en el comentario anterior ha funcionado, ya no me salen los metodos como obsoletos.